# PHP post with square brackets not creating array

Tags: php, post, var-dump, square-bracket

I have used square brackets in forms a few times, however im stumped as the one i'm working on now using Twitter BootStrap (would that make any difference?) is not sending the data(!) - 12 yrs coding and now i'm asking this silly q.

What i could normally do is either manually (or via loop) echo $_POST['itemnum'][0] / $_POST['itemnum'][1] / etc - but its coming back empty..

```
<form  method="POST" action="'.phpself.'" class="form-horizontal" role="form">
...(table with 3 identical rows)..

<tr>
            <td >
            <input type="text" name="itemnum[]" class="form-control" id="inputEmail3" placeholder="Item #"></td>
            <td ><input type="text" name="itemdesc[]" class="form-control" id="inputEmail3" placeholder="Description"></td>
            <td ><input type="number" name="itemqty[]"  class="form-control"  style="max-width:80px;display:inline"  placeholder="Qty"></td>
            </tr>
....

</form>
```

var_dump:

```
array(5) { ["itemnum"]=> string(0) "" ["itemdesc"]=> string(0) "" ["itemqty"]=> string(0) "" ["message"]=> string(24) " d hef s s dvs sd vsd vs" ["submitRFQ"]=> string(0) "" }
```

Comment: Are you sending this form using Ajax?

Comment: nope - regular submit..
<input type="submit" value="submit" class="DashButton" style="margin-top:30px">

Comment: I would suggest using the network inspector of your browser developer tools and make sure it's submitting correctly.

Comment: What are you dumping out? Is it a processed value or the contents of the $_POST variable?

Comment: I don't see a present problem with your code. Sometimes your tags not closed correctly could also be the cause. Could you paste the full HTML?

Comment: Harry: var_dump($_POST) -

Answer (score 0):

sorry guys - i had a CleanFormPost() function that was not suited for multi-dimensional arrays. apologies and thanks again!